# How can I detect file type?

Tags: ruby, file-type

`file` command says file type, but it says "ASCII text", if file is text. However I want to discover what *type* of text it is, e.g. Ruby script, Python script, C++ file, etc. I want to do this using Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can't do it reliably.

However you can be fairly certain by looking at the name of the interpreter in the first [(hashbang) line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).  (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python`, `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, etc.)

In general, however, it is not possible to do reliably.  For example, consider the following program:

```
print "Hello, World!"
```

Is it Python?  or Ruby?  or Perl? -- It is a valid program in all of those languages!

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do it reliably, but probably the closest you can get is seeing if the program is syntactically correct for a given language. Note that this will give false positives! [@maerics’s example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14970189/211563) of `print "Hello, World!"` is one, as is the trivial empty file case (which likely all syntax checkers will pass as okay). You could reduce this by only guessing if only one syntax checker says it’s okay.

Here’s how to check the syntax only in the languages you gave (for more, the [Syntastic Vim plugin](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/tree/master/syntax_checkers) is a good reference):

- C++: `$CC -x c++ -fsyntax-only myfile` (replace `$CC` with your favorite compiler, this command is Clang & GCC compatible.)
- Ruby: `ruby -c myfile`
- Python: `python -m py_compile myfile`

Typically you can just check the exit code of this command, in Ruby you can do so by passing the command to run to [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) and checking if the return value is true.